# How to disable few options in select dropdown based on a condition?

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<select ng-model="data" ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in data">
  <options value="">Select</options>
</select>
```

Here I want to disable 2 options from the select options based on some condition (other `ng-model`). How can I do it. I am new to UI development I searched for it but I see no information.
Here the `data` contains the following content in it

> A - Abcde
>   B - Efghi
>   C - Ijklm
>   D - Mnopq
>   E - Qrstu

The actual ng I want is when the rate is greater than 24000 disable options `B - Efghi` and  `D - Mnopq`.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable with `ng-options` you need a `disable when` added to the query with some condition in it.
Here is a simple example with a hard-coded condition:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array = {
    "A": "Abcde",
    "B": "Efghi",
    "C": "Ijklm",
    "D": "Mnopq",
    "E": "Qrstu",
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <select ng-model="data" 
          ng-options="key as value disable when (key=='B' || key=='D') for (key,value) in array">
    <option value="">Select</option>
  </select>

  <p>{{data}}</p>

</div>
```